# Update all elements in LazyColumn by clicking on one of them

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, composable

I have a LazyColumn that displays a list of items. Each element is a composable function. The function displays a card that expands when you click on it. At the same time, it is necessary that the card that was previously expanded is collapsed.

I tried to do it like this, but it only works if you go to another screen and go back:

```
val expandedProbeId = remember {
                mutableStateOf(-1)
            }
LazyColumn() {
                        items(
                            items = probeList,
                            key = {item: Probe ->  item.id}
                        ) { probe ->
                            Probe(
                                probe = probe,
                                isExpanded = expandedProbeId.value == probe.id,
                                onExpand = {
                                    expandedProbeId.value = probe.id
                                }
                            )
                }
    

@Composable
fun Probe(
    probe: Probe,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    onExpand: () -> Unit
) {
    val expState = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(isExpanded)
    }
    val temperatureFontSizeState: Int by animateIntAsState(
        if (expState.value) 32 else 15,
        tween(300), label = ""
    )
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(4.dp)
            .clickable {
                expState.value = !expState.value
                onExpand()
            }
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(
                        horizontal = 24.dp,
                        vertical = 18.dp
                    ),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = probe.temperature.toString(),
                    fontSize = temperatureFontSizeState.sp
                )
                Text(text = convertTimestampToDateTime(probe.timeStamp))
            }
            val enterFadeIn = remember {
                fadeIn(
                    animationSpec = TweenSpec(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
                    )
                )
            }
            val exitFadeOut = remember {
                fadeOut(
                    animationSpec = TweenSpec(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
                    )
                )
            }
            val exitCollapse = remember {
                shrinkVertically(animationSpec = tween(300))
            }
            val enterExpand = remember {
                expandVertically(animationSpec = tween(300))
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = expState.value,
                enter = enterFadeIn + enterExpand,
                exit = exitFadeOut + exitCollapse,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Column() {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(
                                horizontal = 24.dp
                            ),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
                    ) {
                        Text("Description:")
                    }
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(
                                horizontal = 24.dp,
                                vertical = 9.dp
                            ),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {
                        Text(probe.descr)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll be grateful for ideas.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your code is correct and should work as expected. If it doesn't, problem will be probably somewhere else. Maybe attach the implementation of `Probe()` as well.

Comment: Hey @JanBína ! Thank you for your reply! I added the Probe code to the post I don't think the problem is with the Probe code. The code in LazyColumn will work if all the elements of the column are recomposed when you click on the card. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem actually is in the `Probe` implementation:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Probe(isExpanded: Boolean) {
    val expState = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(isExpanded)
    }

    Button(onClick = { expState.value = !expState.value }) {}
}
```

When you do something like this, `expState` won't be updated when the `isExpanded` argument is changed. The state is created once, `isExpanded` is used as the initial value, but then it's only updated inside of the `onClick`, not when the argument is changed.

The correct approach is to get rid of `expState` completely - you are [hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting) the state, so make `isExpanded` argument the only source of truth and make the parent composable decide if `Probe` should be expanded or not.

Comment: Damn... Looks like I don't fully understand how states and recomposition work... I'll go figure it out :).
Thank you so much for your help! I made an implementation
Probe without expState. It works great!